# FLUTTER: The named parameter 'product' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

This is a body class where i'm stuck in an error, i've tried to fix it by remove a "required" key... but it doesn't work, how can i fix it? Thanks you!

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zeus_app/constant/list_constant.dart';
import 'package:zeus_app/detailpage/categories.dart';
import 'package:zeus_app/product/product.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const Categories(),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
          child: GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
              crossAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
              childAspectRatio: 0.75,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>   ItemCard(),
          ),
        ))
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  //final Function press;
   ItemCard({
    key: Key,
     required this.product,
    //required this.press,
  }):super(key:key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPaddin),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: Hero(tag: "${product.id}", child: Image.asset(product.image)),
        ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

This is product class code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  final String image, title, addColors, price;
  final int id;

  Product(
      {required this.image,
      required this.title,
      required this.addColors,
      required this.price,
      required this.id});
}

List<Product> products = [
  Product(
      title: 'Great Life Tee',
      price: '64.500 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/a1.JPG',
      addColors: '+10 màu',
      id: 1),
  Product(
      title: 'Hen Dress',
      price: '199.500 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/a2.JPG',
      addColors: '+3 màu',
      id: 2),
  Product(
      title: 'Sunflower Big Tee',
      price: '399.000 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/a3.JPG',
      addColors: '+10 màu',
      id: 3),
  Product(
      title: 'Great Life Tee / Her',
      price: '64.500 đ',
      image: 'assets/images/a4.JPG',
      addColors: '+6 màu',
      id: 4),];
```

This is an error I'm stuck in body class, I've tried many ways to fix it, but it's still failed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ItemCard()` widget takes a name argument

```dart
class ItemCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;
  const ItemCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

Provide a product here

```dart
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemCard(product:products[index]),
```

Also, you can make it nullable

Comment: Glad to help, you can check more about [using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)